# Excel download through java servlet

Tags: java, excel, servlets

I have a requirement of downloading excel sheet(HSSF workbook). In the response , I have set the content type and header as

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=user.xls");
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        workBook.write(out);
```

When ever i click the button, it is calling the servlet but the excel is not getting downloaded. In alert I'm getting the response like

??????????????????????????????????????????? Root ???? Entry WorkBook ???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Suggest me any ideas to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: `out.flush();` after writing?

Comment: When I hit the servlet, it should download the excel file, but it's not happening. In front end, when i put the response in alert I'm getting the following "??????????????????????????????????????????? Root ???? Entry WorkBook ???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????"

Comment: out.flush(); is also not working.

Comment: Download the file (application/octet-stream) and check the content (with a hex dump possibly). Maybe it is wrongly produced, like using String, Reader/Writer, which does a "text" conversion. Write it to a file at the spot. Maybe you have some compressing servlet filter or such.

Comment: Try writing to a file before writing to response? This will narrow down the problem to the servlet response.

Comment: I did, it is writing the data into the file and I can see in my local machine where I have specified the path. My requirement is it should download automatically in the downloads when I hit the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the mime type. For example:

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
```

For a more general solution try to use this:

```
    String mimeType = URLConnection
            .guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
    if (mimeType == null) {
        mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    }

    response.setContentType(mimeType);
```

Comment: **No change in the behaviour of the program. Same issue persists.**

Comment: Try to set the content length like this: `response.setContentLength((int) file.length());`

Comment: I tried setting the content length. It is not downloading. Is there any other thing i'm missing

Comment: When i write the workbook to FileOutputStream , it is creating the excel file in my local. But, in response I'm not getting the excel file downloaded.

Comment: What does the network tab of the developer tools show when you inspect the download request?